# Import Audio Markers or Cues to Audition CS5.5

Tags: audition

I want to import Cues from an external source (CUE-File or mp4chaps Simple Chapter Text file) to Audition, or even better yet, permanently stick them to WAV files.

Looking through old documentation for Audition 3 (Windows), I noticed that there used to be an "Import" function for Markers or Cues.

This function is no longer available in Audition CS5.5, and I don't know if CS6 will bring any new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

And as I spent the last two days hunting down a solution, I'll share it with you right away:

**tl;dr:** Use this cross platform & open source tool by the US Government (ya, really) to stick XMP Metadata in the WAV File.
http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/

WAV Files support the "cue " chunk, and this chunk is written by Audition, but I couldn't make it read from this chunk, and related chunks containing the cue names.

But Audition also writes the XMP Metadata, including a somewhat redundant copy of the Cue chunk. And it will also read it back.

So, by generating an XMP file containing the cue information, and sticking it in the XMP chunk of a WAV file, you can import that data to Audition.

For example:

```
<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.2-c003 61.141987, 2011/02/22-12:03:51        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmpDM="http://ns.adobe.com/xmp/1.0/DynamicMedia/">
         <xmpDM:Tracks>
            <rdf:Bag>
               <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                  <xmpDM:trackName>CuePoint Markers</xmpDM:trackName>
                  <xmpDM:trackType>Cue</xmpDM:trackType>
                  <xmpDM:frameRate>f254016000000</xmpDM:frameRate>
                  <xmpDM:markers>
                     <rdf:Seq>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <xmpDM:startTime>18645250f44100</xmpDM:startTime>
                           <xmpDM:name>Marker 01</xmpDM:name>
                        </rdf:li>
                        <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
                           <xmpDM:startTime>69088263f44100</xmpDM:startTime>
                           <xmpDM:name>Marker 02</xmpDM:name>
                        </rdf:li>
                     </rdf:Seq>
                  </xmpDM:markers>
               </rdf:li>
            </rdf:Bag>
         </xmpDM:Tracks>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <dc:format>audio/x-wav</dc:format>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

The format should be self explanatory.

If you want to write your own tool to automate this, follow the [XMP specs from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart3.pdf) concerning WAV files and the XMP chunk, which, ironically is named backwards:

> The XMP in […] WAV is in a chunk with the ID "_PMX", encoded as UTF-8.
>   Note that the ID is backwards, due to a bug in the initial
>   implementation concerning processor byte order.

Here's an iOS App that will generate Audition-compatible XMP files: 
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xmp-marker/id525322095?ls=1&mt=8

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem I solved differently. It depends on your volume and workflow whether it suits. I had a few files marked up with labels in Audacity and wanted to import those label markers into Adobe Audition as marked ranges. I have a simple but manual solution, and since exporting labels from Audacity only allowed for a text file of timecodes I chose not to use Tom's solution because it seemed like there would be many manual steps in any case.

My solution:

1. Open the AUP project file in Audacity
2. Choose to export the labels to a text file (file export labels)
3. Open the unmarked audio file in Audition
4. Lay down the correct amount of markers (converting them to ranges in my case)
5. Copy and paste the time codes from the text file to the Audition marker window

That should do it.

I think it's quicker than rolling an XMP file by hand and converting my source material to WAV and back again. However if there was a tool to convert the label/marker text file into an XMP file and I had a lot of cues to import then Tom's method sounds appealing.

p.s. 
I'm using Audition CS6 on OSX. I find it much better than Audacity overall so that's why I'm switching. Too much destructive editing in Audacity. I like having my originals.